# ADF to Snowflake incremental load and streams

Tags: azure, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-data-factory, incremental-load

I am trying to load files from my Azure blob to Snowflake table incrementally. After which in snowflake, I put streams on that table and load the data to the target table.

I am unable to do incremental load from Azure to Snowflake. I have tried many ways but not working. I am attaching the images of my 2 different ways (pipelines) to do the same.

In this pipeline, I just added 3 extra columns which I wanted in my sink

[image]

In this pipeline, I tried creating conditional splits

[image]

Both of these have not worked out.
Kindly suggest me how to go about this.

Comment: can you add some clarification to what you mean by "incremental", and where it's going wrong? You want to only load new files from the Azure Blob, but it's picking up all of them? You want to insert new records, but the job is truncating before it inserts? You want to load upserts into the table but it's only running inserts?

Comment: I want to load newly inserted records as well as any updated records from the Azure Blob to Snowflake table. And yes, it is only loading inserts. Let me know if you want more info

Comment: Hello @Coder1990, was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by selecting **Allow Upsert** in **sink settings** under the Update method.

Below are my repro details:

1. This is the **staging table in snowflake** which I am loading incremental data to.

[image]

2. **Source file – Incremental data**

a) This file contains records that exist in the staging table (**StateCode = ‘AK’ & ‘CA’**), so these 2 records should be **updated** in the staging table with new values in Flag.

b) Other 2 records (**StateCode = ‘FL’ & ‘AZ’**) should be **inserted** into the staging table.

[image]

3. **Dataflow source settings:**

[image]

[image]

4. Adding `DerivedColumn` transformation to add a column **modified_date** which is not in the source file but in the sink table.

[image]

[image]

5. Adding `AlterRow` transformation: When you are using the Upsert method, AlterRow transformation is a must to include the upsert condition.

a) In condition, you can mention to **upsert** the rows only when the **unique column** (StateCode in my case) **is not null**.

[image]

[image]

6. Adding `sink` transformation to AlterRow with Snowflake stage table as sink dataset.

[image]

a) In **sink settings**, select Update method as **Allow upsert** and provide the Key (unique) column based on which the Upsert should happen in sink table.

[image]

[image]

7. After you run the pipeline, you can see the results in a sink.

a)  As **StateCode AK & CA** already exists in the table, only other column values (flag & modified_date) for those rows are **updated**.

b)  **StateCode AZ & FL** are not found in the stage (sink) table so, these rows are **inserted**.

[image]

Comment: Hi Nihar,

Thanks for your answer. I follow the same setup to implement the Upsert. I carefully checked the SQL statements executed in Snowflake for the ADF task. It seems

1. All rows in the source file will be loaded into Snowflake, but not only the updated rows. In your example, only the updated rows are loaded into Snowflake. Correct me if I am wrong.
2. Since all rows are loaded into Snowflake, the Update SQL statement will update all rows in Snowflake table. But the intention is only to update the delta rows.
Do you have any idea on this?

Thanks.